# logging apache httpasyncclient

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, asynchttpclient

Hi I followed the instructions here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html since it was the only logging instructions I could find on the site, but I was still not able to turn logging on for the httpasyncclient. It works for the typical httpclient, not async. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using logging configuration of the outdated HC 3.x, which obviously does not work neither with the blocking nor the non-blocking HC 4.x clients. You find the correct logging guide here

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html